Upgrade airflow db within docker container
I am trying to upgrade airflow from 2.6.1 to 2.9.1.
The docker container keeps exiting with the errror : ERROR: You need to upgrade the database. Please run airflow db upgrade. Make sure the command is run using Airflow version 2.9.1.
Can I run airflow db migrate -s --from-version "2.6.1" -n "2.9.1" with the container running on 2.6.1 ?
I tried to run airflow db migrate in the Dockerfile, but it is not upgrading the actual db
